# JQueryMobile registering vclick event handler prevents defuault form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am registering a 'vclick' event handler in jquerymobile on a button and on an anchor tag.

```
    <script>
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function(event, ui) {
        $('.show-page-loading-msg').bind('vclick', function() {
            $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Loading...";// "Approved";
            $.mobile.textOnly = false;
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, Randomly things works fine for most of the times, but sometimes, all I see is loading message for infinite time and no default functionality of submitting form of submit button or not showing up new mobile page for anchor tag. Please notice, sometimes it works fine.

Markup:

```
<form id="test" data-ajax="false" action="/test/login" method="post">
    <!--username password textboxes here-->
            <input class="show-page-loading-msg ui-btn-hidden" type="submit" value="Sign In" data-theme="e">
            <a class="show-page-loading-msg" href="/test/home" data-role="button" data-theme="d">Cancel</a>     
    </form>
```

randomly submit button does not submit a form or sometimes even anchor tag does not show up the another page, but they never fail to show loading message.

Comment: Can't say if this will make the issue go away, but in any case: bind() is not recommended since jQuery 1.7 and should be replaced by on().

Comment: I'm using jQuery v1.6.4 and jQuery Mobile v1.0.1

Comment: Maybe you should consider upgrading – versions that old are likely to have a number of bugs that not many people are even aware of anymore since they might have been fixed ages ago. At the very least give the newest version a try and see if you can still reproduce the problem. At least that's what I'd try. ;)

Comment: Try removing `data-Ajax=false` or sit to `true`

Comment: tried upgrading to : jquery-1.8.2 and jquery.mobile-1.3.0
but no luck..same problem. works approx 8 out of 10 times

Comment: What if you use a `button` instead of an `input type="submit"`?

Comment: Another thought - have you checked for any uncaught exceptions?

Comment: @gerrod, great idea for exceptions, let me put them inside try catch and see what happens..

Comment: no exceptions inside the event handler. stuck.
Also, I tried with data-ajax="true" but navigation does not work well with it as it is url based hash.